# Linq to Entities with NameValueCollection

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, namevaluecollection

What is the best way to deal with the problem that you can't use a NameValueCollection
or Dictionary in a LINQ to Entities query?

I know you can assign the value to a temporary string variable and then use that in
your query...but is there any other way?

I get all my input from ASP.Net's Request.Params NameValueCollection and it's cumbersome to introduce a new string variable for each value just so that I can use it in a database query...

```
using (ModelContext db = new ModelContext()) {
    NameValueCollection c = new NameValueCollection();

    c["Name"] = "Foo";

    var query = from p in db.Customers
            where p.Name == c["Name"]
            select p;

    // Exception:
    //  LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
    //  'System.String get_Item ...'
    foreach (Customer customer in query)
        Console.WriteLine(customer.Name);
}
```

Comment: I'd store it into a string variable then use `p.Name.Equals(collectionName);` Did you strip something out of your code? I can't seem to see why create the `NameValueCollection` just to hold the "Foo" `string`. Why not just create a `string` instead of creating the `NameValueCollection`?

Comment: Oh the code is just to demonstrate the general problem. In reality my NameValueCollection comes from a HttpRequest

Comment: Oh, I see. I would really just store the `c["Name"]` into a `string`, that way its more flexible for what you want to do with the value (set all to uppercase, etc.)